# Python Keras not outputting a Probability vector when using Softmax and Transfer Learning

Tags: python, keras

I am using keras to do a classification problem where I have to classify images provided into one of three classes using transfer learning of the VGG16 imagenet. Below is my code.

```
import keras
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_dir = r"./Iris_Imgs/"
batch_size = 10
img_size = 224

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                            validation_split = .3)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory = train_dir,
    target_size = (img_size, img_size),
    batch_size = batch_size,
    class_mode = 'categorical',
    subset = 'training')

test_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory = train_dir,
    target_size = (img_size, img_size),
    batch_size = batch_size,
    class_mode = 'categorical',
    shuffle = False,
    subset = 'validation')

from keras.applications import VGG16
from keras.models import Model
vgg_conv = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
vgg_conv.summary()

    from tensorflow import keras
    from tensorflow.keras import layers
    from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
    from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
    from keras.layers import Flatten
    from keras.layers import Dense
    last = vgg_conv.output
    x = Flatten()(last)
    x2= Dense(1024, activation = 'relu')(x)
    x3 = Dense(512, activation = 'relu')(x2)
    my_pred = Dense(3, activation= 'softmax')(x3)
    
    my_model = Model(vgg_conv.input, my_pred)
    #my_model.summary()
    
    i = 0
    
    for layer in my_model.layers[:-1]: # <---- Freezing the last layer for transfer learning to complete correctly
        layer.trainable = False
        #i = i+1
        #print(i, layer.name)
    my_model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['categorical_accuracy'], )
    
    fit = my_model.fit(train_generator, 
                      steps_per_epoch = 10,
                      epochs = 10,
                      validation_data = test_generator, 
                      validation_steps = 5)
```

However when I do:

```
import numpy as np
preds=my_model.predict(test_generator)
preds = np.argmax(preds, axis = 1)
print(preds)
print(test_generator.classes)
```

I get the following output:

```
preds = [0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2]
test_generator.classes = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]
```

My understanding of the softmax layer is that it should be outputting a probability of classes versus actual class predictions. Is it doing this because I froze the weights in the last layer for purposes of transfer learning?

If so, how do I get the array with the distributions in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by removing line `preds = np.argmax(preds, axis=1)`

Is you wish to print the class probabilities, just the following should be fine:

```py
import numpy as np

preds = my_model.predict(test_generator)
print(preds)
```

Note:
`argmax` returns the indices of the maximum values along an axis.